# XAudio2 mono source played as a 3D sound is heard only in right speaker, regardless of distance and position

Tags: xaudio2

I am having problem setting up a 3D space sound effect in XAudio2. The sound effect that I am using is mono but the result is playing constantly, irrelevant from the distance and positioning of the listener and emitter, always on right channel. Here is the code of the play sound effect function:

```
void SoundSystem::Channel::PlaySoundEffect(Sound& s, float pitch, float volume)
{
    assert(pSource && !pSound);

    s.AddChannel(*this);

    XAUDIO2_VOICE_DETAILS details;
    SoundSystem::Get().pMaster->GetVoiceDetails(&details);

    X3DAUDIO_DSP_SETTINGS DSPSettings = { 0 };
    FLOAT32* matrix = new FLOAT32[details.InputChannels];
    DSPSettings.SrcChannelCount = s.mFormat.nChannels;
    DSPSettings.DstChannelCount = details.InputChannels;
    DSPSettings.pMatrixCoefficients = matrix;

    X3DAudioCalculate(SoundSystem::Get().X3DInstance, &SoundSystem::Get().Listener, &s.Emitter, 
        X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_MATRIX | X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_DOPPLER
        | X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_LPF_DIRECT | X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_LPF_REVERB
        | X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_REVERB,
        &DSPSettings);

    pSound = &s;
    xaBuffer.pAudioData = s.pData.get();
    xaBuffer.AudioBytes = s.nBytes;
    pSource->SubmitSourceBuffer(&xaBuffer, nullptr);

    // Apply X3DAudio generated DSP settings to XAudio2
    pSource->SetFrequencyRatio(DSPSettings.DopplerFactor);
    pSource->SetOutputMatrix(SoundSystem::Get().pMaster, s.mFormat.nChannels, details.InputChannels, DSPSettings.pMatrixCoefficients);
    pSource->SetOutputMatrix(SoundSystem::Get().pMaster, 1, 1, &DSPSettings.ReverbLevel);
    XAUDIO2_FILTER_PARAMETERS FilterParametersDirect = { LowPassFilter, 2.0f * sinf(X3DAUDIO_PI / 6.0f * DSPSettings.LPFDirectCoefficient), 1.0f }; // see XAudio2CutoffFrequencyToRadians() in XAudio2.h for more information on the formula used here
    pSource->SetOutputFilterParameters(SoundSystem::Get().pMaster, &FilterParametersDirect);
    XAUDIO2_FILTER_PARAMETERS FilterParametersReverb = { LowPassFilter, 2.0f * sinf(X3DAUDIO_PI / 6.0f * DSPSettings.LPFReverbCoefficient), 1.0f }; // see XAudio2CutoffFrequencyToRadians() in XAudio2.h for more information on the formula used here
    pSource->SetOutputFilterParameters(SoundSystem::Get().pMaster, &FilterParametersReverb);

    pSource->Start();
}
```

Here is the Listener:

```
void SetListener(const glm::vec3& front, const glm::vec3& up, const glm::vec3& position, const glm::vec3& velocity) {
    Listener.OrientFront = { front.x, front.y, -front.z };
    Listener.OrientTop = { up.x, up.y, -up.z };
    Listener.Position = { position.x, position.y, -position.z };
    Listener.Velocity = { velocity.x, velocity.y, -velocity.z };
}
```

And here is the emitter:

```
void SetEmitter(const glm::vec3& front, const glm::vec3& up, const glm::vec3& position, const glm::vec3& velocity) {
    Emitter.OrientFront = { front.x, front.y, -front.z };
    Emitter.OrientTop = { up.x, up.y, -up.z };
    Emitter.Position = { position.x, position.y, -position.z };
    Emitter.Velocity = { velocity.x, velocity.y, -velocity.z };

    Emitter.pCone->InnerAngle = 0.0f;
    // Setting the inner cone angles to X3DAUDIO_2PI and
    // outer cone other than 0 causes
    // the emitter to act like a point emitter using the
    // INNER cone settings only.
    Emitter.pCone->OuterAngle = 0.0f;
    // Setting the outer cone angles to zero causes
    // the emitter to act like a point emitter using the
    // OUTER cone settings only.
    Emitter.pCone->InnerVolume = 0.0f;
    Emitter.pCone->OuterVolume = 1.0f;
    Emitter.pCone->InnerLPF = 0.0f;
    Emitter.pCone->OuterLPF = 1.0f;
    Emitter.pCone->InnerReverb = 0.0f;
    Emitter.pCone->OuterReverb = 1.0f;

    Emitter.CurveDistanceScaler = 1.f;
}
```

Note that I am using OpenGL as the graphics API and have a right handed coordinate system so I negate the z component. Anything that I am doing wrong and have the sound only on one speaker and in full volume? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to remove the line :

> pSource->SetOutputMatrix(SoundSystem::Get().pMaster, 1, 1, &DSPSettings.ReverbLevel);

and everything worked out great. For anyone who is struggling with this.

Comment: Any information you can share about why this line was causing the problem?

Comment: I got this code from an example on the github page of DirectX. It could be a mistake on their side as the SetOutputMatrix function is used only for setting the matrix coefficients calculated in the X3DAudioCalculate

Comment: Can you provide a link?  The reverb level is usually used to drive the output from a second link from a source voice to a submix voice where the reverb is applied. In *that* case, you'd set the output matrix using the reverb level but to a *different* voice than master (i.e. the pSource output goes to master -and- to a submix voice).